# Convert a text file into a dictionary list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file in this format (in_file.txt):

```
banana 4500 9 
banana 350 0 
banana 550 8 
orange 13000 6
```

[image]

How can I convert this into a dictionary list in Python?

Code:

```
in_filepath = 'in_file.txt'

def data_dict(in_filepath):
    with open(in_filepath, 'r') as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            title, price, count = line.split()

    d = {}
    d['title'] = title
    d['price'] = int(price)
    d['count'] = int(count)

    return [d]
```

The terminal shows the following result:

```
{'title': 'orange', 'price': 13000, 'count': 6}
```

Correct output:

```
{'title': 'banana', 'price': 4500, 'count': 9}, {'title': 'banana', 'price': 350, 'count': 0} , ....
```

Can anyone help me with my problem? Thank you!

Comment: Read in complete as pandas dataframe, and then use todict, have a look at "orient = 'record' ". That might fulfill your demands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
titles = ["title","price","count"]
[dict(zip(titles, [int(word) if word.isdigit() else word for word in line.strip().split()])) for line in open("in_file.txt").readlines()]
```

or:

```
titles = ["title","price","count"]
[dict(zip(titles, [(data:=line.strip().split())[0], *map(int, data[1:])])) for line in open("in_file.txt").readlines()]
```

your approach(corrected):

```
in_filepath = 'in_file.txt'

def data_dict(in_filepath):
    res = []
    with open(in_filepath, 'r') as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            title, price, count = line.split()

            d = {}
            d['title'] = title
            d['price'] = int(price)
            d['count'] = int(count)
            res.append(d)
        
    return res

data_dict(in_filepath)
```

why? because

1. ->

```
    d = {}
    d['title'] = title
    d['price'] = int(price)
    d['count'] = int(count)
```

is out of `for` loop and run only once and when ‍‍`for` be finished and then you have just one element

2. you return your last element and didn't use others and use must create a list and append every element at the last line of `for` loop (saving) and at last, return result

@Rockbar approach:

```
import pandas as pd

list(pd.read_csv("in_file.txt", sep=" ", header=None, names=["title","price","count"]).T.to_dict().values())
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a list of dictionaries (array of objects). So it would be best if you appended `dictionary` into a `list` each time you created it from a line of text.

Code

```
in_filepath = 'in_file.txt'


def data_dict(in_filepath):
    dictionary = []
    with open(in_filepath, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            title, price, count = line.split()
            dictionary.append({'title': title, 'price': int(price), 'count': int(count)})

    return dictionary


print(data_dict(in_filepath))
```

Output

```
[
    {"title": "banana", "price": 4500, "count": 9},
    {"title": "banana", "price": 350, "count": 0 },
    {"title": "banana", "price": 550, "count": 8},
    {"title": "orange", "price": 13000, "count": 6}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file line-by-line and then create `dict` base keys that define in the first.

```
keys = ['title', 'price' , 'count']
res = []
with open('in_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:

     # Or in python >= 3.8
     # while (line := file.readline().rstrip()):

        tmp = [int(w) if w.isdigit() else w for w in line.rstrip().split() ]
        res.append(dict(zip(keys, tmp)))
print(res)
```

---

```
[
    {'title': 'banana', 'price': 4500, 'count': 9}, 
    {'title': 'banana', 'price': 350, 'count': 0}, 
    {'title': 'banana', 'price': 550, 'count': 8}, 
    {'title': 'orange', 'price': 13000, 'count': 6}
]
```